# Excel VBA macro that filters time stamp data which is pulled from a connected SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I currently have a sheet that has a connection to a SQL table that is pulling time stamped records. I need to filter this table by a week to week basis and extract the number of elements linked to each week range. The time stamp is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss.sss" and I need to convert that to usable variable. I have tried every variable type to get this information into a form that I am able to filter it, however none work. Each time I try to insert the time stamp into a variable I get the error "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method". Does excel not recognize the time stamp as a usable value (string, date, or double)?

Comment: I would help if you show what you've tried

Answer (score -1):

I think you are struggling with two issues, as per my knowledge String is the best suitable data type for Timestamp. And the error you are finding is due to mismatch between versions of the applications. 
Since you are pulling data from the Oracle better use Dataset method or use the SQL AddIn.